# Functional filter unique elements in sequence is not as good as imperative

Tags: functional-programming, scala, stream

Can you please help me fulfill the following?

Requirements:

1. Create an iterable with unique elements. Their order should be preserved:

   ```
   a | b | a | c → a | b | c
   ```
2. The program must continually write to stdout.
3. The program must be computationally efficient.
4. The program must be written in the [Functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) paradigm.

---

Attempts:

1. Imperative style (violates 4):

   ```scala
   def filterUnique[A](inSeq: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = {

     val inSeqIt = inSeq.iterator
     val mutableSet: scala.collection.mutable.Set[A] =
       scala.collection.mutable.Set.empty

     def go(it: Iterator[A], s: scala.collection.mutable.Set[A]): Stream[A] = {
       if (it.hasNext) {
         val cur: A = it.next
         if (mutableSet.contains(cur)) {
           go(it, s)
         } else {
           s += cur
           Stream.cons(cur, go(it, s))
         }
       } else {
         Stream.empty
       }
     }
     go(inSeqIt, mutableSet).toSeq
   }
   ```
2. Functional style with recursion (violates 2):

   ```
   @tailrec
   def filterUnique[A](
       inSeq: Seq[A],
       set: Set[A] = Set.empty,
       outSeq: Seq[A] = Seq.empty
   ): Seq[A] = {

       if (inSeq.isEmpty) outSeq
       else {
         if (set.contains(inSeq.head))
           filterUnique(inSeq.tail, set, outSeq)
         else
           filterUnique(inSeq.tail, set + inSeq.head, outSeq :+ inSeq.head)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Functional style with streams (violates 3; very unreadable):

   ```
   def filterUnique[A](inSeq: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = {

     def grownSetSeq: Stream[Set[A]] = (
       (Set.empty: Set[A])
         #:: Set(inSeq.head)
         #:: inSeq.tail.toStream
           .zip(grownSetSeq.tail)
           .map(
             x ⇒ if (x._2.contains(x._1)) x._2 else x._2 + x._1
           )
     )

     inSeq.zip(grownSetSeq).filter(x ⇒ !x._2.contains(x._1)).map(_._1).toStream
   }
   ```

---

Trivia: this is part of one of my personal projects: https://github.com/fmv1992/fmv1992_scala_utilities.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't provide code, we review code you've written. Depending on your problem, another site of the [StackExchange network](//stackexchange.com/) can help you. Please see our [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: 2 and 4 aren't really compatible with each other. One of the cores of FP is use of pure functions, and a pure function doesn't "continually write to stdout".

Comment: "continually write to stdout"? None of the 3 write anything to stdout. Continually or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried this for a couple of hours (even before posting here) and the following approach proved useful:

Work your way from the imperative approach back to the functional approach (rather than rewriting from scratch):

```
def filterUnique[A](inSeq: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = {

  def go(it: Iterator[A], s: Set[A]): Stream[A] = {
    if (it.hasNext) {
      val cur: A = it.next
      if (s.contains(cur)) {
        go(it, s)
      } else {
        Stream.cons(cur, go(it, s + cur))
      }
    } else {
      Stream.empty
    }
  }

  go(inSeq.iterator, Set.empty).toSeq
}
```

Relevant commit is: [4a6e844](https://github.com/fmv1992/fmv1992_scala_utilities/commit/4a6e844e474fb7360465e2b7977345a566e34123).